# Double free of child object after using the copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

I am having trouble figuring out why (it seems like) an object is being destructed twice.

If i create a object of a class (B) which contains an object of another class (A) and i copy this object. the copied object is destructed twice. Altough it looks like this. I am unable to figure out this output.

I have created the following (minimum?) example which seems to trigger my issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        myCtr = ++ctr;
        printf("class A default Constructor - object id: %u\n", myCtr);
    }

    A(const A<T> &a2) {
        myCtr = ++ctr;
        printf("class A copy constructor - object id: %u\n", myCtr);

    }

    ~A()
    {
        printf("class A destructor - object id: %u\n", myCtr);
    }

    void add(T item) {
        /* Irrelevant */
    }

private:
    uint64_t myCtr;
    static uint64_t ctr;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {

    }

    B(char * input, uint32_t len) {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            characters.add(input[i]);
        }
    }

    B(const B &b2) {
        characters = A<char>(b2.characters);
    }

    ~B() {

    }


private:
    A<char> characters;
};

template <class T>
uint64_t A<T>::ctr = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    B b1 = B((char *)"b1", 2);
    B b2 = B(b1);

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
class A default Constructor - object id: 1
class A default Constructor - object id: 2
class A copy constructor - object id: 3
class A destructor - object id: 3
class A destructor - object id: 3
class A destructor - object id: 1
```

object id 3 is destructed twice while object id 2 is not destructed at all.

I am using the following compiler:
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26429.4

In case you down vote. Please specify why. I will gladly try to improve my question.

Comment: Note that `characters = A<char>(b2.characters);` is **copy assignment**, which is generated automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to follow the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  If you implement a non-trivial destructor, copy/move assign/construct, you must implement all 5, or give a good reason why not, or delete them.

You implemented destory and copy ctor.  You neglected the other 3.  Add them.

What more `characters = A<char>(b2.characters);` your copy ctor calls a copy assignment.  Which you don't track, which is why your count is off.  You assign over the counter.

Comment: I implemented the constructor in my example? Or am i doing something wrong?
I created a follow up question regarding an issue i am encoutering using the move assignment operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783053/c-move-assignment-to-uninitialized-object

Answer (score 3):

The confusion comes from this line.

```
characters = A<char>(b2.characters);
```

A **default generated assignment operator** copies object 3 to object 2, including `myCtr`.

`myCtr` is not `const`, so it may change during its lifetime.  If you need a value to remain the same, make it `const`.

Here is a version of your class that will behave the way you expect.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A()
        : myCtr( ++ctr )
    {
        printf("class A default Constructor - object id: %u\n", myCtr);
    }

    A(const A<T> &a2)
        : myCtr( ++ctr )
    {
        printf("class A copy constructor - object id: %u\n", myCtr);

    }

    A<T>& operator=(const A<T> &a2) {
        // Copy what's needed from a2 here.
        return *this;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        printf("class A destructor - object id: %u\n", myCtr);
    }

    void add(T item) {
        /* Irrelevant */
    }

private:
    const uint64_t myCtr;
    static uint64_t ctr;
};
```